# Store data in a for loop

Tags: c#

I have a for loop and what I'd like to do is to store the data of every for cycle in C#.
At the moment it only stores the datas of the last iteration.

Attached my code. Thanks a lot!

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (i <= k - p - 1)
    {
        alpha[i] = 1;
        NewCPVector[i] = CPVector[i];
    }
    if (k - p <= i && i <= k-1)
    {
        alpha[i] = (FinalKnotsVector[k] - Initialknots[i]) / (Initialknots[i + p + 1] - Initialknots[i]);
        NewCPVector[i] = alpha[i] * CPVector[i] + (1 - alpha[i]) * CPVector[i - 1];
    }
    if (i >= k)
    {
        alpha[i] = 0;
        NewCPVector[i] = CPVector[i - 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also specify what are the values of k, p and n?

Comment: As others hinted at, if you choose sane and sensible values for `n`, `k`, and `p`, your loop should place stuff in the `alpha` and `NewCPVector` arrays/collections in every iteration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your arrays hold double values. (However it could be other types, like float or decimal) you just have to specify that type in the declaration of the list
You could save the data in a List this way:

```cs
List<double> data = new List<double>();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (i <= k - p - 1)
    {
        alpha[i] = 1;
        data.Add(NewCPVector[i] = CPVector[i]);
    }
    if (k - p <= i && i <= k-1)
    {
        alpha[i] = (FinalKnotsVector[k] - Initialknots[i]) / (Initialknots[i + p + 1] - Initialknots[i]);
        data.Add(alpha[i] * CPVector[i] + (1 - alpha[i]) * CPVector[i - 1]);
    }
    if (i >= k)
    {
        alpha[i] = 0;
        data.Add(CPVector[i - 1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed!